# How to resolve JPA @PersistenceContext nullpointer exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jboss-arquillian

My appologies, i am fairly now to JPA and this may be a dumb user error, but...

Here is my pom's dependency section:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0-beta-2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Everything looks happy compiles and runs, until...

JPAService.java:

```
...
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager; <-- null
...
```

My understanding is that my persistence unit should be auto-magically dropped in where i have used the @PersistanceContext annotation, please correct me here if there is more that i need to do somewhere.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="datasource">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/<dbName></jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Using shrinkwrap to create my test container/deplyment i have this code:

```
        File[] mavenImports = Maven.resolver()
                .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                .importRuntimeDependencies()
                .resolve()
                .withTransitivity()
                .asFile();

        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "skeleton-ert-tests.war")
                .addAsLibraries(mavenImports)
                .addClass(ArquillianTest.class)
                .addPackages(true, "org.<packageName>")
                .addAsResource("jbossas-managed/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsResource("jbossas-managed/test-orm.xml", "META-INF/orm.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("beans.xml", "beans.xml");
```

And the beans.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd"
>
</beans>
```

Wondering what i might be missing, or what more is needed?

EDIT 1:
per chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-'s suggestion i removed field injection and removed injection entirly

```
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("datasource");
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
```

When the class is instantiated, i step through the 2 assignment's. factory is assigned and appears to be working as expected, however, when i call 'factory.createEntityManager()' i get a null pointer exception. Some digging and it appears to be that i dont have a transactionInterceptor. So, i created a boilerplate one and added:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"value="org.<company>.utils.MyInterceptor"/>
```

But to no avail, same error & the interceptor is still not set in the Factory i get back.

Comment: Where are you creating beans for EntityManager? Spring can't inject the beans which are not created or provided by the user. Your entity manager depends on the data source you are configuring along with other properties.

Comment: @vaibhavsahu
PSA, not using spring.
i have a boilerplate beans.xml file in /test/resources/beans.xml that is copied to /main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml by shrinkwrap in the createdeployment.

Edited the post to show both.

Comment: You almost certainly have the same problem: `@PersistenceContext` is only injected into objects that are managed by the container (whether Spring or something else).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- i am using JBOSS/WildFly, but im not sure that it is configured correctly since the tests are failing.

Comment: If possible, replace field injection with constructor injection. It helps to prevent exactly this sort of problem and to identify it early (fail-fast) when it does appear.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- thanks for the suggestion, please see EDIT 1 above, thanks.

Comment: Removing all injection doesn't prevent the hidden dependency, it just hides it in a different way.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Regardless of how the dependency gets there, somewhere (either by me, or by jboss) 'Persistence.createEntityManagerFacroty(**)' is being called. That function call returns an incompletely constructed factory. That is what i think i need to resolve first here.